# ObjcRuntime.Selector not working on the expected object (xamarin)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

I need to respond to the NSStatusBarButton click to show a menu, which unfortunately only has the property "Action" to add a click handler.
The "Action" property requires a selector.

The method I use to handle the click is the following:

```
[Action("StatusBarClicked:")] public void StatusBarClicked(NSObject sender)
{
    // do something 
}
```

And I do the following to assign the button action:

`statusBarButton.Action = new Selector("StatusBarClicked:");`

Now, it all works when I do this in the DidFinishLaunching method of the app delegate and the StatusBarClicked method is a method of the AppDelegate class.

When I wrap the status bar code in a separate class and declare the method and the selector in that class, it doesn't work (StatusBarClicked is not called).
Strangely enough, if I keep the StatusBarClicked method also in the AppDelegate, that one is called instead:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var statusItem = NSStatusBar
            .SystemStatusBar.CreateStatusItem(NSStatusItemLength.Square);

        var button = statusItem.Button;
        button.Image = NSImage.ImageNamed("test");
        button.Action = new Selector("StatusBarClicked:");
   }

    [Action("StatusBarClicked:")] public void StatusBarClicked(NSObject sender)
    {
        // never called
    }
}
```

I must be missing something, any idea?

Comment: I just realised the NStatusBarButton also has an Activated property that accepts a delegate. I would still be curious to understand why the selector does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set an action the selector is sent to the `Target` property of the NSControl when the action triggers.

If the target is null the application travels up the responder chain to find the first object that responds to the selector. The app delegate is in the responder chain, that is why that works.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428885-target?language=objc

If you want to use your custom class as the target I think it needs to subclass `NSObject`

After you make sure your class extends NSObject you can add this to your constructor:

```
button.Target = this;
```